# How to insert with increasing numbers of line

Tags: vim, edit

This is a small part of the file, the original file has hundreds of lines.

Line 1 below insert the new line Numbers 1, 2, 3 lines below the new line number 2, 3, and so on, are as follows.

How to use gVim command and function to achieve the change from above to below.
I'm using gVim of windows platform.

Before the modification

```
hsd
xlfh
1lm
2lm
3lm
4lm
5lm
6lm
7lm
8lm
9lm
slm
s1lm
......
```

After the modification

```
hsd
1
xlfh
1lm
2
3
2lm
3lm
4lm
4
5
6
5lm
6lm
7lm
8lm
7
8
9
10
9lm
slm
s1lm
......
```

Comment: I doubt there's a simple way to do this with a short series of Vim commands. You could do some Vimscript, (or weird things with macros) but at that point you might as well use a real scripting language to do what you want.

Comment: [When you tried to solve this yourself](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), with which part did you get stuck? Identifying the algorithm? Writing the Vimscript? Executing the Vimscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why you would need to do this, but if you need this often, consider a function inside .vimrc:

```
function! Nameme()
    1
    let mov = 1
    let start = 1
    let inc = 0
    while 1
        call append(line('.'), range(start, start+inc))
        let mov += 2
        let inc += 1
        let start += inc
        if mov + line('.') > line('$')
            break
        endif
        execute mov + line('.')
    endwhile
endfunction
```

Then you could just `:call Nameme()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in Vim, merging another file containing the numbers to insert (created by /bin/cat -n for example), here is the beginning.

```
gg         go to first line
o1<esc>"ayy   a (will increase) initialized to 1
"byy        b (will be cumsum of a) initialized to 1
qz          loop this:
:.,<c-r>a   advance by a lines
"bp         put a(a-1)
```

... but I will only continue if you format your question so that it does not end up [deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19470/do-you-ever-not-upvote-a-question-that-you-answer/48048#comment669887_48048)